# Wordpress Nav not displaying 4th level?

Tags: wordpress

Well, I must have tried every possible resource on the tinterweb to achieve what I want to... to no avail :-(

I'm using the built in WordPress menu system to manage the main menu. I am (at this stage) simply trying to output all the items within the menu tree. The menu needs to support 4 levels. Using the standard wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Primary Navigation', 'depth' => 0 )); is fine for 3 levels but as soon as the walker has reached level 3, nothing else is output?

Am I missing something? The depth value '0' tells the walker to go to every branch of the tree so whats happening?

Can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should show all levels, but if level 4 is not showing, it is probably related to the theme's style. Perhaps the fourth level is not defined in the style for the menu, or it is set as hidden.

Could you post a link or the menu part of the file style.css?